# Как удаленно проверить, что компьютер включился

Tags: c#, c++

Есть серверный компьютер, к которому подключены 20 клиентских. Расстояние между ними не большое, можно их соединить не только через сетевые платы.

Как программно проверить, что клиентские компьютеры включились?

Есть мнение, что решение нужно искать в интерфейсе GPIO. То есть один пин соответствует одному компьютеру, но мне не совсем понятно, как это реализовать?

Comment: А ping не годится?

Comment: К сожалению нет. Дело в том, что мне нужно проверить все этапы загрузки: включение, старт биоса, запуск ОС. Смысл в том, чтобы точно знать по какой причине компьютер не включился.

Comment: Думаете это возможно?

Мне кроме видеокамеры по IP ничего в голову не приходит (шучу, конечно же).

Comment: Контролировать потребителя в розетке, если потребление началось, значит начал работать блок питания. Если мало потребляет, значит вычисления не начались и винда ещё не загрузилась... :-) (шутка конечно, но может напишешь контроллер розетки).

Comment: эх шутники)) А задача реальная! Есть такая карточка - Digital Input\Output Card (DIO). Она может считывать значения пинов. Это на сервере. На клиетах есть итерфейс GPIO, который работает так: напряжение появилось - сигнал = 1, биос отработал - сигнал = 0. Это в первом приближении, я просто надеялся, что кто-то может подробнее объяснить и помочь с реализацией.

Comment: Всем спасибо за советы, ценные и не только) Если кому-то интересно как данный проект будет реализован - обращайтесь.

Answer (score 3):

Решение уже давно есть ! [Платы сетевого удалённого управления](http://article.techlabs.by/full/51_1531.html). С помощью них можно выполнять удалённо настройки BIOS.

Comment: Спасибо, но этот вариант не подходит)) Мне не нужно управлять удаленным компьютером, мне нужно получить от него данные о том, как прошел запуск. Пример: комп не включился, причин может быть несколько, выделим основные - нет напряжения, проблемы с биосом либо на его уровне, ОС не поднялась. А когда ОС поднялась мне ничего не нужно настраивать ни в биосе ни в компе))

Answer (score 2):

Думаю без хорошей аппаратной поддержки, вашу задачу не решить, например потому что:

-Проверку питания можно реализовать, но только аппаратным методом.(Контроллер розетки=) уже предлагали)

-Далее БИОС, ну тут сложнее, программно никак, только средствами аппаратного хардкора.
Описывать тут их не буду, самому смешно=) По крайней мере такой реализации не видел.

... ect

Answer (score 2):

Скажем так - задача в общем случае нерешаема. Действительно, здесь требуется глубокое знание аппаратной платформы ПК и ее частных нюансов. Например, можно было б в каждый ПК установить т.н. post card с каким-либо внешним интерфейсом и считывать статус загрузки БИОСа, но даже универсальной схемы кодов между разными материнскими платами нет. Еще нюанс, что сетевой интерфейс подымается весьма рано - ведь ф-ция загрузки по сети есть в любой современной плате. Поэтому получается, что можно забиться на пингуемость компьютера и для разумных задач этого будет достаточно. Затем вывести состояние всех компьютеров на некую программную панель и следить за ним. Понятно, что когда ПК будет отображаться как оффлайн ВСЕ РАВНО ПОТРЕБУЕТСЯ вмешательство сисадмина - независимо от реальной причины сбоя - проблемы связи (переткнуть сетевой шнур), проблемы с ОС (переустановка или замена накопителя на заранее подготовленный с исправной копией ОС) или аппаратные проблемы (диагностика и ремонт конкретного ПК или его замена на резервный).

Answer (score 0):

Только идеи. http://www.insidepro.com/kk/046/046r.shtml
Если есть возможность сделать такое, значит можно и передать какие-нибудь данные.
Это биос, ну с операционкой то же. А вот именно включение компа не знаю, кажется только проверкой наличие тока в цепи. Т.е. подцепляешься к какому-нибудь выводу и определяешь есть ли на нем питание. У ноутов Usb начинает работать только при включении, у пк не знаю. Куда там ещё воткнуться можно)

Answer (score 0):

А если подключиться к интерфейсу вывода post-карты, обеспечить передачу данных к пинам arduino, поднять на нём web-server и читать оттуда данные? Естественно, что каждая материнская плата будет известна и в зависимости от неё уже интерпретировать код состояния.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, стоит обратить внимание на [Intel® Active Management Technology](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/intel-active-management-technology.html). Имеется в наличии SDK, но, само собой, требуются определенные знания и заточено это все под определенную платформу.